# Why can I not grab the extrusion from the front view to the right view? (On the nose.)

Tags: vertices, mirror-modifier

[image]

I am unable to grab from the right side. I think it has something to do with the mirror modifier but am unsure how to fix it. 3 things fixed this, but then other problems happened. First, I turned off merge but lost merges. Second, I turned off the edit mode button. Third, I turned off the x-axis. Both the second and third made me lose the mirror side. Seems to have something to do with the mirror modifier, but I am unsure what is wrong.

Comment: When using the mirror modifier, only one "side" is editable, the other is just a copy (mirror) of it.

Comment: Ok, so then how should I edit the right view?

Comment: If you want to edit the right side separately from the left side, you have to apply the mirror modifier first (though this means your future actions will no longer be mirrored)

Comment: I also think that the mirror might be getting in the way when you try to select the thing. To solve the problem of losing symmetry, you can go into tool options and turn on symmetry. It works fairly well as long as you don’t create new vertices.

Comment: Okay, just to be clear, what does it mean to add the mirror modifier first? Like before what exactly? Two, should you add a mirror object to help with symmetry instead of just putting the x or y-axis; which only seems to work on the front view on not the right view?